# Facebook app in IE - Sometimes getUser() returns 0 although the user already has been connected

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, sdk

I using in PHP SDK and sometimes when I'm connecting to my FB app on Internet Explorer the function getUser() returns 0!
Someone knows this weird issue? After some attempts it is getting connected.

It seems that there are cases that facebook doesn't identify the user. Any advice?

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY,
));

// Get User ID
$fbUserId = number_format($facebook->getUser(), 0, '', '');
```

Comment: Can you post your code so we can help diagnose the problem?

Comment: Yes, you can see the code attached now.

Comment: How can I close irrelevant questions?

Comment: What happens if your remove the number_format?

Comment: I indeed don't need the number_format. Anyways, it's not the problem :)